# Cloud functions get current user

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My problem is the following: I have a system that has some asset information (e.g. a book) and this asset has some characteristics (e.g. title, current owner, color). I want to be able to change current owner by just executing an HTTP request such as presented in the introduction: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

At first it seems simple, however I am unable to get the current user ID or the browser session email, for example. I tried to look for solutions before, using realtime database triggers: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

my current code below:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
//const user = admin.auth.user();

function dir(object) {
    stuff = [];
    for (s in object) {
        stuff.push(s);
    }
    stuff.sort();
    return stuff;
}

// Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into the
// Realtime Database under the path /messages/:pushId/original
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const original = req.query.text;
  // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.
  const snapshot = await admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original});
  //const snapshot2 = await admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: email});
  // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
  res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref.toString());
});

exports.impersonateMakeUpperCase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const appOptions = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
      appOptions.databaseAuthVariableOverride = context.auth;
      console.log(dir(context))
      const app = admin.initializeApp(appOptions, 'app');
      const uppercase = snap.val().toUpperCase();
      const ref = snap.ref.parent.child('uppercase');

      const deleteApp = () => app.delete().catch(() => null);

      return app.database().ref(ref).set(uppercase).then(res => {
        // Deleting the app is necessary for preventing concurrency leaks
        return deleteApp().then(() => res);
      }).catch(err => {
        return deleteApp().then(() => Promise.reject(err));
      });
    });

exports.simpleDbFunction = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      if (context.authType === 'ADMIN') {
        // do something
        console.log(snap.val(), 'written by', context);
      } else if (context.authType === 'USER') {
        console.log(snap.val(), 'written by USER', context);
      }
```

Every time I tried to get from context.auth.uid or context.auth.token.email it returns null, it seems that context.auth is null. Maybe there is some step I am skipping.

I just want to get the current user or the browser session user and update the book id i sent in the request for the new owner. I want the interface to be as simple as possible, like scan a bar-code or one-click.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting null for context.auth, that means there was no user signed to the client app at the same of the database change.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#accessing_user_authentication_information

Comment: What you mean by "there was no user signed to the client app at the same of the database change". I am connected to to the dashboard and I am logged in the Angular app I made. This method is called by HTTP request. (sorry for the lack of understanding, I am very new to firebase)

Comment: You're showing three functions in your code.  Which one isn't working the way you expect?  What exactly are you doing to trigger it that should have auth information available?

Comment: simpleDbFunction context, should have auth field , but has only:


oioi written by { eventType: 'google.firebase.database.ref.create', params: { pushId: '*' }, resource: { service: '*', name: '*' }, timestamp: '***', eventId: '****', authType: 'ADMIN' }

If I try to do console.log(context.auth.uid) it will return null, for example.

Comment: authType: 'ADMIN' means that the change was made not by a user of the app, but by some backend code, or a change from the Firebase console.  Auth information is only available when users of the mobile app make a change while signed in to the app.

Comment: I see, so I need to authenticate the user before doing anything with the database. I was looking in the function-samples in firebase repository, but could not find any example that fits this case. Do you know any example to authenticate user and update database with user uid?

Comment: Follow the documentation to integrate Firebase Authentication into your app.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth

Comment: Thank you for the information, I believe that I was using functions for the wrong application. I could do the expected behavior by querying the route parameters in angular. The good side of this approach is that I already had authentication setup on my angular application, therefore the work was minimal.

Answer (score 0):

For the interested ones, if you have already an angular application, this behavior can be achieved by querying parameters from the route, check this:
https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/